# URL mapping for self hosted WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf, config

I have a WCF service DLL and when I debug it gets auto hosted and this custom URL mapping works:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "widget/{myid}")]
    public Widget GetWidget(string myid) {...
```

My config file has:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c03f5f7f11d50a3b" />
  </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

However I want to host inside my own service so I think now instead it uses the `system.serviceModel` section of the config instead and so I can't use `System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule`.

I have the self hosted service working; however, it is automatically calling my URL `GetWidget` instead of `widget/{myid}`.  So it is not using my `WebInvoke` attribute.

If I'm manually hosting my WCF service in my own Windows NT Service via a ServiceHost object, how can I still support custom URLs with the same type of mapping?

Comment: How did you configure your service host? Add your system.servicModel configuration section and code which creates your `ServiceHost`.

Comment: Standard basic HTTP.  There is no modules section allowed in that section thouugh...